# Using a Regular Expression, how to ignore a given character

Tags: java, regex, databricks

Good afternoon,

I'm part of a migration project from SQL Server to DataBricks (Apache Spark) and while we're enjoying all the benefits of DB, I must admit I'm missing all of those lovely Microsoft SQL functions.

As part of my migration, I'm trying to write a regular expression to find the first instance of a "-" or a "+" and return all characters after this.

Here's my regular expression so far:
`\+(.*)|\-.*`

Here's my *complex* test set:

dlfsdlfkgjbsdfg / sdklfjgsdfgsdfg-**sdfgsdfg** / sdfgjh-**sdfgsdfg** / sdfg+**sdfgsdfg** / sdfgsdgfhf4

The bold text is what I expect to return, but currently I'm seeing the plus and the minus chars returning.

[image: Screenshot of my code from RegExr]

I've tried following examples but it seems that I'm missing a trick because I can either highlight everything after (but including) the chars, or just the char itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: test comment you know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
\+(.*)|\-.*
```

Matches either

a plus followed by anything and capturing that anything

or

a hyphen and anything and doing nothing with it.

You should use the character class and then a capturing .*, like

```
[+-](.*)
```

or a noncapturing alternation (of one each of + and -) and capturing .* like

```
(?:\+|-)(.*)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extract matches of the following regular expression with the *single-line* or *DOTALL* flag set, which cause the dot to match line terminators as well as all other characters.

```
(?<=[+-]).*
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/VVkOIb/1/)

`(?<=[+-])` is a *positive lookbehind* (supported by Java) which asserts that the current location in the match is preceded immediately by the first plus or minus character.

Comment: 1) `(?<=...)` is a *positive* lookbehind (though the explanation is right). 2) *The regex will match an empty string if the string contains no plus or minus character.* - This is wrong, because the *positive* lookbehind *requires* its pattern match, so if there is no `+` or `-`, there will be *no match at all*.

Comment: I assume my answer was downvoted for two incorrect statements I made in the text that I've corrected. The regex has not changed. In such situations, I advocate pointing out the problems in a comment, then deleting the comment after the corrections are made, so as to not distract from the answer.